# Can I remove all '>' in front of the code?

Tags: r, rstudio

suppose I copy some code from console in Rstudio to my code file

get:

```
> good = 1
> bad = 2
> comment = 5
> good = 1
> bad = 2
> comment = 5
... 1000 lines
```

is there a way to remove all > at the beginning of each line?

Comment: You may not need to [copy from console], check your `.Rhistory` file. Also *History* panel  in RStudio, it provides *To Source* and *Save* options.

Comment: Consider using the {reprex} package instead of copying from the console

Comment: @margusl hmm... That is interesting while may be not so intuitive. Sometimes using the tools is a skill need to train. But knowing the existence of the function is the first step.

Answer (score 4):

On my Mac I can hold `option` and select all the `>` in straight line

[image]

On windows, I think it is the `Alt` key.

Comment: and Alt on Ubuntu as well

Answer (score 2):

All decent IDEs will provide some functionality to replace with regex patterns, e.g., in RStudio you could use the pattern `^>\s` (with the "Regex" box ticked below the "Replace" text box) in the "Find" and nothing in the "Replace" text box and then hit "All" (next to "Replace") to replace all occurrences. Of course regex is not completely necessary here, you could also simply find `>`  (note the space) and then click "All" with the "Replace" box empty to replace it with nothing.

If you want it to only occur in some part of the code, you can select the part and then tick "In selection" to only remove it there.

Comment: didn't think this simple way, thank you

Comment: @JonSpring No, the regex pattern matched only `> ` (followed by a space) at the start of a new line. That is what the `^` is for.